# Values in array are not being printed correctly

Tags: c, arrays

I am making a record of sales according to product sales and salesman sales. However when I print the total sales according the product (the last for loop), the program malfunctions and the values aren't being printed as they actually are. Where am i wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int sp[4][5];
    int i,j,sum,slp=1;
    printf("Slip\n");
    printf("Enter The Dollar Value of Product Sold:\n");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {

        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%d Salesperson, %d Product:",i,j);
            scanf("%d",*(sp+i)+j);
        }
    }
    printf("\nSales Person\tProduct 1\tProduct 2\t\tProduct 3\t\tProduct 4\t\tProduct 5\n");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",slp);
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("\t\t%d\t",*(*(sp+i)+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
        slp+=1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) 
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++) 
        {
            sum=sum+*(*(sp+i)+j) ;
        }
        printf("Sales of Salesperson %d is = %d\n",i,sum);
        sum=0;
    }
    sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<4;++i) 
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;++j)
        {
            sum=sum+*(*(sp+j)+i); 
        }
        printf("Sales of the Product %d is = %d\n",j,sum);
        sum=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*the values aren't being printed as they actually are*" - Please show input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: Are you trying to use`*(*(sp+j)+i)`, instead of `sp[i][j]` for some strange reason?  I don't understand the reasons to overcomplicate the notation.  Why don't use then something like `i[j[sp]]`, which is equivalent to the above, and far more obscure?

Comment: It is better to initialize variables before use, than to reset them at the end.  I think this is the reason you put `sum=0` at the end of the loop bodies... but not only is a difficult way to do things, as you have been replied in an answer, but also a way to overcomplicate one's life.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1** -  You need to initialize `sum`, in the first iteration of the `for` loop its value is undefined.

**2** - In the cycle:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        sum = sum + *(*(sp + j) + i);
    }
    printf("Sales of the Product %d is = %d\n", j, sum);
    sum = 0;
}
```

You have the limits of the two `for`s the other way around which causes the loop to reach outside the bounds of the array, it must be `i < 5` and `j < 4`. And the printed index should be the `i` not the `j`.

**The corrected code:** [**Live demo**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/RobustOrderlyNumerator)

```
//...
sum = 0; //<-- here initialize sum
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        sum = sum + *(*(sp + i) + j);
    }
    //salespetson 0 is not very neat (i + 1 to add 1 to index)
    printf("Sales of Salesperson %d is = %d\n", i + 1, sum); 
    sum = 0;
}
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) //<-- 5 here
{ 
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) //<-- 4 here
    {
        sum = sum + *(*(sp + j) + i);
    }
    printf("Sales of the Product %d is = %d\n", i + 1, sum); //<-- here also
    sum = 0;
}
//...
```

If your goal is to tinker with pointers to see how they work, I can understand that but the the real world of coding using the brackets notation `sp[i][j]` is much more readable and therefore appreciated.

You can also use format specifiers to neatly format your output, something like:

```
char* header[6] = {"Sales Person", "Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3", "Product 4", "Product 5"};

printf("%10s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s\n", header[0], header[1], header[2], header[3], header[4], header[5]);
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("%6d  ", slp);
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        printf("%15d", *(*(sp + i) + j));
    }
    printf("\n");
    slp += 1;
}
```

Input:

```
Slip
Enter The Dollar Value of Product Sold:
Salesperson 1, Product 1: 1
Salesperson 1, Product 2: 2
Salesperson 1, Product 3: 2
Salesperson 1, Product 4: 2
Salesperson 1, Product 5: 3
Salesperson 2, Product 1: 2
Salesperson 2, Product 2: 2
Salesperson 2, Product 3: 3
Salesperson 2, Product 4: 2
Salesperson 2, Product 5: 3
Salesperson 3, Product 1: 32
Salesperson 3, Product 2: 2
Salesperson 3, Product 3: 3
Salesperson 3, Product 4: 3
Salesperson 3, Product 5: 2
Salesperson 4, Product 1: 3
Salesperson 4, Product 2: 3
Salesperson 4, Product 3: 2
Salesperson 4, Product 4: 3
Salesperson 4, Product 5: 2
```

Output:

```
Sales Person      Product 1      Product 2      Product 3      Product 4      Product 5
     1                1              2              2              2              3
     2                2              2              3              2              3
     3               32              2              3              3              2
     4                3              3              2              3              2
Sales of Salesperson 1 is = 10
Sales of Salesperson 2 is = 12
Sales of Salesperson 3 is = 42
Sales of Salesperson 4 is = 13
Sales of the Product 1 is = 38
Sales of the Product 2 is = 9
Sales of the Product 3 is = 10
Sales of the Product 4 is = 10
Sales of the Product 5 is = 10
```

I also corrected the prints for the input:

```
printf("Salesperson %d, Product %d: ", i + 1, j + 1);
```

Comment: Much appreciated! Thanks :)